# Handling null value when casting to float

Tags: php, arrays, json, highcharts, encode

I'm on a project using Highcharts.

A bit of php file:

```
$sql    =   "SELECT unix_timestamp(`datetime`) as `datetime`, `temp_cellule`, `temp_exterieur` FROM `tablebase`";
$result =   mysql_query($sql);
$data   =   array();
while   ($row   =   mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $datetime   +=  3600;   //GMT+1
    $datetime   *=  1000;   //UNIX_TIMESTAMP to java
    $data[] =   array((float)$datetime,(float)$temp_cellule);           
    $data2[]=   array((float)$datetime,(float)$temp_exterieur);
}

$array[]    =   json_encode($data);
$array2[]   =   json_encode($data2);
```

With this code: `$data2[]=  array((float)$datetime,(float)$temp_cellule);`

I get a good format but Highcharts does not recognize the value "null" because it's not a float so it's converted to 0 :

```
[[1362133360000,25],[1362136955000,0],[1362140579000,35]
```

But, if I use: `$data[] = array($datetime,$temp_cellule);` **(without casting to float)** I get the good format for "datetime" and "null" but not for temp_cellule because of **" "**  :

```
[[1362133360000,"25"],[1362136955000,null],[1362140579000,"35"]]
```

And I want:

```
[[1362133360000,25],[1362136955000,null],[1362140579000,35]]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by using a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It will check for a condition then execute the second argument *(what is between the `?` and the `:`)*, else it will execute the third argument *(what is after the `:`)*.

```
$data[] = array((float)$datetime, is_null($temp_cellule) ? null : (float)$temp_cellule);
```

A ternary operator is a shorthand operator for an if-else then assign operator. As it returns the value of the second or third argument.

This would be the same thing as writing it like that :

```
if(is_null($temp_cellule)){
    $data[] = array((float)$datetime, null);
} else {
    $data[] = array((float)$datetime, (float)$temp_cellule);
}
```

---

**Note that** depending on how many times this case is present in your code you could make an utility function with it.

```
function handleFloat($value){
    return is_null($value) ? null : (float)$value;
}
```

Then you would just write :

```
$data[] = array((float)$datetime, handleFloat($temp_cellule));
```

This could help to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: These days you could just define the return type in the function declaration:

`function handleFloat($value): ?float {  return $value;  }`

Answer (score 3):

You can do the type casting by condition;

```
$data[] =   array((float)$datetime,(is_null($temp_cellule) ? null : (float)$temp_cellule))
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but if i remplace: 

    `$data[] =   array((float)$datetime,(float)$temp_cellule);`

BY

    `$data[] =   array((float)$datetime,(isnull($temp_cellule) ? null : (float)$temp_cellule));`

I get  SCREAM: 

    Error suppression ignored for 
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function isnull()

Comment: Oh sorry, I've forgot to put an underscore between is and null. Correct name for the function is `is_null`